# "NOR" or "AND"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Which one sounds better? Are both 1 and 2 correct?

> 1. I don't eat bread, pancakes, and toast.
> 2. I don't eat bread, pancakes, nor toast.

Comment: Which is the double negative?  And wouldn't "or" be a better choice?

Comment: "I don't eat bread, pancakes or toast." ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"or" would suffice, as in:

> I don't eat bread, pancakes, or toast.

but if you're particular about emphasizing the inclusive idea, try

> I eat neither bread nor pancakes nor toast.

Comment: "I don't eat bread, pancakes or toast." 

?

Comment: Right. I'll update the answer to make that explicit.